# Binary pipes with SBCL

Tags: subprocess, common-lisp, sbcl

How do I set up binary pipes on the stdin and stdout of the subprocess using `sb-ext:run-program`? I'd like to have streams with element-type `(unsigned-byte 8)` to talk to the subprocess in Lisp.

`run-program` takes an `:external-format` argument but as far as I can tell it's only about text encodings, not binary. SBCL ships with a [test program](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/tests/run-program.impure.lisp) that does binary I/O but it defines a custom stream class using Gray streams, which seems advanced enough that there has to be an easier way.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, `sb-ext:run-program` is responsible for creating intermediate streams when you pass the `:stream` option. The other answer shows that you can directly write bytes to it if you want to. But If you inspect how `run-program` is implemented, you can build the streams yourself by using the same functions called by `run-program` to generate an intermediate unix pipe, and read/write to it using binary streams.

```
(defpackage :so (:use :cl :alexandria))
(in-package :so)
```

Define an auxiliary function that closes a file descriptor while handling errors as warnings:

```
(defun unix-close/warn-on-error (file-descriptor)
  (multiple-value-bind (status error) (sb-unix:unix-close file-descriptor)
    (prog1 status
      (unless (eql error 0)
        (warn "Unix close error: ~S" error)))))
```

Then, a macro that temporarily create a unix pipe:

```
(defmacro with-unix-pipe ((read-fd write-fd) &body body)
  (with-gensyms (first second)
    `(multiple-value-bind (,first ,second) (sb-unix:unix-pipe)
       (if ,first
           (unwind-protect
                (multiple-value-bind (,read-fd ,write-fd)
                    (values ,first ,second)
                  ,@body)
             (unix-close/warn-on-error ,first)
             (unix-close/warn-on-error ,second))
           (error "Unix pipe error: ~s" ,second)))))
```

However, run-program expects streams, not file descriptors. Here you have a macro that binds a variable to a stream tied to a file descriptor:

```
(defmacro with-fd-stream% ((var fd direction &rest fd-args) &body body)
  (check-type direction (member :output :input))
  (with-gensyms (in%)
    `(let ((,in% (sb-sys:make-fd-stream ,fd ,direction t ,@fd-args)))
       (unwind-protect (let ((,var ,in%))
                         (declare (dynamic-extent ,var))
                         ,@body)
         (close ,in%)))))
```

And the macro that does the same for a pair if in/out file descriptors:

```
(defmacro with-fd-streams (((in read-fd &rest read-args)
                            (out write-fd &rest write-args))
                           &body body)
  `(with-fd-stream% (,in ,read-fd :input ,@read-args)
     (with-fd-stream% (,out ,write-fd :output ,@write-args)
       ,@body)))
```

Finally, you can test your code with the following:

```
(let ((ub8 '(unsigned-byte 8)))
  (with-unix-pipe (read write)
    (with-fd-streams ((in read :element-type ub8)
                      (out write :element-type ub8))
      (fresh-line)
      (sb-ext:run-program "dd"
                          '("if=/dev/random" "count=1" "bs=64")
                          :search t
                          :output out
                          :error nil
                          :wait nil
                          :status-hook (lambda (p)
                                         (unless (sb-ext:process-alive-p p)
                                           (close out))))
      (sb-ext:run-program "hd"
                          '()
                          :search t
                          :input in
                          :output *standard-output*
                          :wait t))))
```

Answer (score 3):

The first test that you linked already seems to show that you can simply send bytes to the streams created with `:input :stream` and `:output :stream`.

I'd suggest using `uiop:launch-program` instead for portability:

```
(let ((pri (uiop:launch-program "cat" :input :stream :output :stream)))
  (write-byte 43 (uiop:process-info-input pri))
  (force-output (uiop:process-info-input pri))
  (read-byte (uiop:process-info-output pri)))
```

=> `43`

Comment: You're right about the test. But I can't replicate it: `(defvar p (sb-ext:run-program "/bin/cat" () :wait nil :input :stream :output :stream))` and then `(write-byte 123 (sb-ext:process-output p))` causes an error `... is not a binary output stream`. According to `(stream-element-type (sb-ext:process-output p))` it's a character stream, as expected. SBCL 1.5.6 on Mac.